# Revolution Slider Last Slide not Showing

Tags: wordpress, plugins, slider, slide, revolution-slider

The third slide in one of my Revolution Sliders is not showing up.  All the other sliders on my site are functioning properly, including the one from which the malfunctioning slider was duplicated.

Already tried clearing my cache and viewing in different browsers

Here is the link: http://gregorywalsh.net/videos/documentaries

Answer (score 1):

In your second slide you're missing a closing `<i>` tag. Adding `</i>` before the closing `</div>` tag should fix your issue

[image]